# Web Scraping in Python

Tags: python, web-development, scraping

Do I need to learn advanced python programming skills in order for me to do web scraping using python? Or I should watch tutorials about web scraping and at the same time learning with python in it. I don't have any experience in python because I am a Laravel developer and it is my first time doing such job in web scraping.

Answer (score 0):

Web scraping in Python using [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) is quite simple, but you'll need to know the basics of Python and Python's data types, flow control etc. You'll need to know about string and list manipulation and parsing and simple conditions.